# canvas to image and then upload to server

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvas, upload

Im trying to save a canvas div and then upload it to the server but i cant manage to make it work. 
so, this what i do:

1. i create a canvas div where i will paint with paperjs
2. i save that canvas div (dataToURL method)
3. i try to upload it, but i doesn't work.

this is the web:
[www.davidpenuela.com](http://www.davidpenuela.com)

I tested uploading an image to my server with jquery file uploader ([test jquery uploader](http://davidpenuela.com/test/)) and that script works, but i can make it work when saving from my canvas.

[canvas2image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) is not working for me, it doesnt upload anything.

EDIT:
manage to make it work, I will post the way of doing it soon.
Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't work" is useless for helping you. Exactly what doesn't happen? The file arrives corrupted? Doesn't arrive at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get it it work because it is not a file upload.  File uploads use encoded form data with a  `multipart/form-data` content type.  You client code is posting data that is not form encoded and has a `canvas/upload` content-type.  You need to update your server code to make it aware of the 'canvas/upload' content type, or find a way to form encode the image before upload.

Comment: I had one error cause i moved the file from place to test it. So, now i put it where it has to be, (assets/php/testSave.php) and we get no error but still, i see no changes when trying to upload the image...

Comment: The site is giving a 404 for me

Comment: @Marc B, it doesn't upload the content. But reading what mikerobi said maybe is where the problem is.

Comment: @mikerobi, thanks! its working. I thought about what you said but didn't i kept the 'canvas/upload'